# How can I implement a variable length row-based storage in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++17

I am trying to implement a variable-length row-based storage system in C++. The idea is that each row in this storage system should be able to hold data of varying lengths and different types. For example, the first row could be [1, 8.6, "hello"], and the second row could be [2, 9.6].

To achieve this, I initially planned to use tuples with variadic templates for each row. Each row would be stored as `std::tuple<Types...>`, and the entire storage would be represented as a `std::vector<std::tuple<Types...>>`.

However, the issue I'm facing is that when I try to declare a Map class to hold this storage, I need to explicitly declare its parameter types—e.g., `Map<int, double, std::string>`. This approach restricts me from inserting records of different lengths and types into the same Map instance.

Here's a simplified snippet to demonstrate my point:

```
template <typename... Types>
class Tuple {
private:
    std::tuple<Types...> data;
public:
    Tuple() : data() {}

    Tuple(Types &&... args) : data(std::forward<Types>(args)...) {}
}

template <typename... Types>
class Map {
private:
    vector<Tuple<Types...>> record;
public:
    void addRow(Types &&... args) {
        record.emplace_back(std::forward<Types>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Is there a way to create a Map class where each row can hold different lengths and types of data? How can I implement this in C++?

Comment: The solution boils down to `std::variant` or `std::any`. This is a bit of an XY problem though.

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level. The complete type of all objects must be defined at compile time. This is fundamental to C++, there are no workarounds.

Comment: The closest I can think of is `std::vector<std::vector<std:variant<bool,int,double,std::string>>>` but in general C++ is a strongly typed language and it is recommmended be as typesafe as you can be. Figuring out types at runtime is just very frragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't describe such structure, using C++ syntax. Type definitions in C++ are setting relevant object's storage representation in stone, once program is compiled.

That doesn't mean that this is isn't possible. You have two options:

1. Create a dynamic structure by using polymorphism. See Adapter, Proxy, Flyweight patterns.
2. If you REALLY need a contiguous structure (stream) of data in memory, you're on a long and thorny path to create own memory pool or protobuf library. can you use one of those existing ones?